# DBIx::Class::ResultSet Update or Create on multiple unique constraints

Tags: perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I was wondering if it is possible update_or_create on multiple unique constraints in dbix

Ex From Cpan:

```
 my $cd = $schema->resultset('CD')->update_or_create(
    {
      artist => 'Massive Attack',
      title  => 'Mezzanine',
      year   => 1998,
    },
    { key => 'cd_artist_title' }
  );
```

What I would like to do

```
   my $cd = $schema->resultset('CD')->update_or_create(
    {
      artist => 'Massive Attack',
      title  => 'Mezzanine',
      year   => 1998,
    },
    { key => {'cd_artist_title','year' }
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out: you have to define the unique constraint in the Controller with [`add_unique_constraint`](http://p3rl.org/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSource#add_unique_constraint).

Comment: `s/Controller/ResultSource/;`